# ROS Listener (Android)

Tags: ros, android-teleop, ros-hydro, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I have set up a navigation stack on my PC and now I'm trying to run a slightly modified copy of android_teleop. Everything seems to work, but the android app does not receive any messages, although I can see them in rviz on the PC and I can see that the android node is connected to the correct topic using rqt_graph. The published topic (/virtual_joystick/cmd_vel) is working.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/132341/ros-listener-(android)/) by [Jordan Markov](https://answers.ros.org/users/12346/jordan-markov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-02-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2014-02-26**:
It's not the missing ROS_IP/ROS_HOSTNAME problem?

**Comment by [Jordan Markov](https://answers.ros.org/users/12346/jordan-markov/) on 2014-02-26**:
It's not that, because the application connects to the master and successfully sends messages to the cmd_vel topic. Also it looks like it is subscribed to the other topics, but it doesn't receive the messages, just like if they are not published.
Is there a firewall on the android phone I need to disable?

**Comment by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) on 2014-02-27**:
Not that I know of, but I haven't done alot of testing on different devices to be sure. Do recheck the ROS_IP settings though, if I remember correctly, publishing can be ok, but subscribing will fail.

**Comment by [CalisM](https://answers.ros.org/users/4352/calism/) on 2014-12-28**:
Sounds like a one-way route. Have you tested pinging from master to subscriber and vice versa? It mostly is a "route add -net 10.20.30.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gateway 10.20.30.1" problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am having the same problem!
Did you find a solution.
When I run the Teleop Hyrdo downloaded from Playstore ,it works fine with no problem.
However, when I upload the android_tutorial_teleop to my android device, the robot is unresponsive.
When I make rostopic info on the cmd_vel topic, I found the following

rostopic info virtual_joystick/cmd_vel
Type: geometry_msgs/Twist
Publishers:

- /android/virtual_joystick (http://192.168.1.2:46089/)
  Subscribers: None

There is no subsriber.
However, when I run the Telop Hydro downloaded from PlayStore, it shows the following

rostopic info /turtlebot/application/android/virtual_joystick/cmd_vel
Type: geometry_msgs/Twist
Publishers:

- /android/virtual_joystick (http://192.168.1.2:37236/)
  Subscribers:
- /mobile_base_nodelet_manager_turtlebot01_3181_5535754284978469755 (http://192.168.1.9:52341/)

The turtlebot is subscribed and responds to the command.

I really could find what is the issue with the code of the Tutorial found in android_core (hydro).

I hope to receive some help on this

A

---

Originally posted by [Anis](https://answers.ros.org/users/4199/anis/) with karma: 253 on 2014-12-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Jordan Markov](https://answers.ros.org/users/12346/jordan-markov/) on 2015-01-05**:
Hi,
I gave up with this problem a couple of months ago. After my research I suspect that the Android version I'm using is not working. I managed to run the teleop app on an emulator with older version of Android, Honeycomb as long as I remember.
Anyway, your problem seems different than mine.